# Null check operator used on a null value (FutureBuilder)

Tags: flutter, snapshot, dart-null-safety, flutter-futurebuilder, null-check

I am receiving the above null check error code with snapshot. I have investigated a number of similar questions on Stack overflow, but don't seem to get a fix to my problem. I am fairly new to flutter still and would really appreciate some help.

Here is my code.

```
  var db = DatabaseConnect();

  Todolist({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: db.getTodo(),
          initialData: const [],
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
            var data = snapshot.data;
            var datalength = data!.length;

            return datalength == 0
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text('no data found'),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: datalength,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) => Todocard(
                      id: data[i].id,
                      title: data[i].title,
                      creationDate: data[i].creationDate,
                      isChecked: data[i].isChecked,
                      insertFunction: () {},
                      deleteFunction: () {},
                    ),
                  );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`snapshot.data` will first return null when the data is being fetched and that is why the result of `snapshot.data` is nullable.

You're getting the error because you're using the null-check operator on the `data` variable in its null state in this line below:

```dart
var datalength = data!.length;
```

**Solution:**

You should check your `data` variable if it is null and show a progress indicator if that is true.

If the null check is false, you can get the length of the data.

Then you display the empty state message if the length is empty and display the actual data if the length is not empty.

Your builder method can be updated to this below:

```dart
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.data;
  if (data == null) {
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  } else {
    var datalength = data.length;
    if (datalength == 0) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('no data found'),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: datalength,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => Todocard(
          id: data[i].id,
          title: data[i].title,
          creationDate: data[i].creationDate,
          isChecked: data[i].isChecked,
          insertFunction: () {},
          deleteFunction: () {},
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data you are getting from `snapshot.data` is `null`.
Instead of storing it in the variable data try using `print(snapshot.data);` and then you'll see that it returns null. So when you check if `datalength == 0` instead of trying to check `snapshot.data == null` it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check if the db.getTodo() function has a ? return type, if it does it mean that when it's null the future thinks the function is return.